# Reduce a Riccati Equation to a Bernoulli Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've seen plenty of proofs and exercises where people reduce a Riccati equation to a linear equation, but not the intermediate step of a Bernoulli equation. I'm trying to reduce the Riccati equation $y' = p(t) + q(t)y + r(t)y^2$ to a Bernoulli equation, which has the form $y' + p(t)y = f(t)y^n$, with the substitution $y = y_1 + u$.

I'm having some trouble understanding this particular substitution since the variables $y_1$ and $u$ are not defined. If I just follow the direction of "substitute the equation," I immediately get confused when I attempt to find $y'$ since I can't tell if we get $y' = y_1' + u'$ or $y' = 0$.

EDIT: I completely forgot to include the fact that $y_1$ is a particular solution of the equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Try to think not in terms of variables, but in terms of solution functions. You had an unknown function $y(t)$ that satisfies Riccati equation. Also you have one particular solution of this equation, $y_1(t)$. Let $u(t) =y - y_1$: this is an unknown function (since $y(t)$ is unknown). What differential equation does it satisfy? Differentiate $u(t)$ and take into account that $y(t)$ and $y_1(t)$ both satisfy Riccati equation.

Comment: Ah this makes sense! Since $y_1(t)$ satisfies the DE, we can say that $y_1'(t) = p(t) + q(t)y_1 + r(t)y_1^2$. Then I assume we plug in the substitutions $y'(t) = u'(t) + y_1'(t)$ and $y(t) = u(t) + y_1(t)$ into the original DE. We then get a $y_1'(t)$ term, so we can use the substitution $y_1'(t) = p(t) + q(t)y_1 + r(t)y_1^2$. Is this on the right track?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I've reduced it to a Bernoulli: $u' + [-2r(t)y_1+q(t)]u = r(t)u^2$, so the Bernoulli $p(t) = -2r(t)y_1 + q(t)$ and $f(t) = r(t)$.

Comment: Seems to be correct. All terms like $p(t)$ (*in notation of Riccati, not Bernoulli equation*) and $y_1(t)^2$ should vanish.